# About finding footer control inside gridview inside in formview in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have formview control. Inside formview control their is one gridview. In gridview i have FooterTemplate(In footertemplate i have textbox control to add text)to add text. To find that control i have written code as follows:

```
 GridView mygridview = (GridView)FVAddCustomer.FindControl("mygridview");
TextBox txtFName1 = (TextBox)mygridview.FooterRow.FindControl("txtFName1");
```

Is this right or any other way? because when i find textbox value then its getting null?
Please help me?

```
  <asp:GridView ID="mygridview" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowFooter="True" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#336666" BorderWidth="3px" CellPadding="4" GridLines="Horizontal" BorderStyle="Double" Width="100%" OnRowEditing="mygridview_RowEditing" OnRowCancelingEdit="mygridview_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowUpdating="mygridview_RowUpdating" Visible="false">
       <FooterStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#333333" />
       <PagerStyle BackColor="#336666" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
       <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#339966" ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="True" />
       <HeaderStyle BackColor="#336666" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
       <Columns>
          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="First Name">
             <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:Label ID="lblFName1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("FirstName")%>'></asp:Label>
             </ItemTemplate>
             <EditItemTemplate>
                  <asp:TextBox ID="txtFName1Edit" runat="server" Width="90px"></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
               <asp:TextBox ID="txtFName1" runat="server" Width="90px"></asp:TextBox>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit">
            <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkEdit" runat="server" Text="Edit" CommandName="Edit" CausesValidation="false" OnClick="lnkEdit_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
              <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkUpdate" runat="server" Text="Update" CommandName="Update"></asp:LinkButton>
              <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkCancel" runat="server" Text="cancel" CommandName="Cancel"></asp:LinkButton>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkAdd" runat="server" Text="Add" CommandName="Add" Width="90px" OnClick="lnkAdd_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
            </FooterTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>
```

Thank you.
Asp.net C#

Comment: Where do you call this code? Do you have called FormView.DataBind/GridView.DataBind before?

Comment: yes i have called gridview.databind in pageload

Comment: You havent answered my question where you're trying to get `txtFName1`. Remember also that FormView has 3 different FormViewModes. If it is currently in Edit-Mode and the GridView is in ReadOnly ItemTemplate, then you cannot access it.

Comment: i have called this code in lnkadd button click event ,lnkadd button is inside gridview( Footer template)

Comment: I have added gridview in insertitemtemplate, but even if i add gridview out of formview then also its not finding value of text box

Comment: Then it's even simplier to get `txtFName1` from the LinkButton-Click Eventhandler: `var footer = (GridViewRow)((WebControl)sender).NamingContainer; var txtFName1 = (TextBox)footer.FindControl("footer");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*From the comments:*

Do you have called FormView.DataBind/GridView.DataBind before?

Remember also that FormView has 3 different FormViewModes. If it is currently in Edit-Mode and the GridView is in ReadOnly ItemTemplate, then you cannot access it.

Try this to get the TextBox from the LinkButton's click-event handler:

```
private void lnkadd_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    var footer = (GridViewRow)((WebControl)sender).NamingContainer;
    var txtFName1 = (TextBox)footer.FindControl("footer");
}
```

Edit: if this does not work, you can try to handle the [GridView's RowCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand.aspx):

```
protected void mygridview_RowCommand(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Add") {
        var txtFName1 = (TextBox)((GridView)sender).FooterRow.FindControl("txtFName1");
    }
}
```

Edit2:

You should bind your GridView to it's DataSource only if `!IsPostBack`. The best place to do this is in the FormView's DataBound Event:

```
protected void FormView1_DataBound(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    switch (FormView1.CurrentMode) {
        case FormViewMode.Insert:
            var mygridview = (GridView)((FormView)sender).FindControl("mygridview");
            //Bind your GridView here'
            break;
    }
}
```

On this way you ensure that the GridView will be rebound automatically when the FormView gets databound. If the FormView changes it's mode to `Insert`, you have to `DataBind` it even if the DataSource is `null`!

Comment: i used this code but txtFName1 value getting as null(its not finding txtFName1)

Comment: I posted my markup in my question please see it & suggest to do any changes

Comment: @abc: try to use the RowCommand(see my edit). Are you binding the GridView even on postbacks from page_load?

Comment: i have added rowcommand event then also its not working, i am binding gridview in pageload, i have not used if(!ispostback)

Comment: @abc: You should check if `!IsPostBack`. Otherwise the TextBox value would be empty even when the user has entered something. But that can hardly explain your problem to find the TextBox .

Comment: when i use !ispostback then i cant see gridview

Comment: @abc: In which template of the FormView is the GridView? Do you rebind the FormView to it's DataSource on every PostBack or only if `!IsPostback`(recommended)? You should reference the GridView from FormView's DataBound Event only and also DataBind it there.

Comment: Insertitemtemplate used, i bind gridview in pageload event on every postback if i used !ispostback then i cant see gridview.

Comment: @abc: have a look at my edits, do you DataBind the FormView when it changes into Insert-Mode?

Answer (score 0):

I found that my grid should only be filled when `(!IsPostback)` occurs in the pageLoad event. Like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        FillGrid();
    }
}
```

and then I performed Insert operation which was successful

```
protected void CustomerGridview_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
        bool flag = false;
        if (e.CommandName.Equals("Insert")) 
        {
            TextBox txtNewName = (TextBox)CustomerGridview.FooterRow.FindControl("txtNewName");                
            DropDownList ddlNewGender = (DropDownList)CustomerGridview.FooterRow.FindControl("ddlNewGender");
            DropDownList ddlNewType = (DropDownList)CustomerGridview.FooterRow.FindControl("cmbNewType");
            CheckBox chkNewActive = (CheckBox)CustomerGridview.FooterRow.FindControl("chkNewActive");
            if (chkNewActive.Checked) flag = true;
            else
                flag = false;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conection);
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand command = con.CreateCommand();
            SqlTransaction transaction;
            // Start a local transaction.
            transaction = con.BeginTransaction();
            // Must assign both transaction object and connection 
            // to Command object for a pending local transaction
            command.Connection = con;
            command.Transaction = transaction;

            try
            {
                command.CommandText = "Insert into Contact (Name,Sex,Type,IsActive) values('" + txtNewName.Text + "','" + ddlNewGender.SelectedValue.ToString() + "','" + ddlNewType.SelectedValue.ToString() + "','" + flag + "')";
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                transaction.Commit();
                Message.Text = "Record has been saved!!";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Message.Text = "Error Occured!!";
                try
                {
                    transaction.Rollback();
                }
                catch(Exception ex2)
                {
                    Message.Text = "Transaction RollBack!";
                }
            }   
            FillGrid();
        }
    }
```